# Enabling metrics on static Azure website pages: GetWebContent API is not available

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

As shown in image below, step 7 of this official Azure tutorial: [Enable metrics on static website pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to?tabs=azure-portal#enable-metrics-on-static-website-pages) states:

```
Check the box next to GetWebContent in the Values selector to populate the metrics report.
```

But there is no `GetWebContent` API available in the `values` dropdown (ordered alphabetically) shown below:

**Question**: Why GetWebContent api is missing here. Is there any alternative api for that in the below list?

**Note**: Clicking on the image will provide a better view of the list:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the steps below:

1.In the left menu `Diagnostic settings(classic)`, configure the settings as screenshot below:

[image]

2.In web browser, visit the static website url(like https://yy9.z5.web.core.windows.net/) many times.

3.In azure portal -> storage account -> Metrics(it may take a few minutes, if the `GetWebContent` api does not appear, please wait and try click the Refresh button), you can see `GetWebContent` api is in the list:

[image]

Comment: It's working now. Following sentence from your step 2 helped: `it may take a few minutes, if the GetWebContent api does not appear, please wait and try click the Refresh button`